# How can I convert each parameter in a variadic function template to another type and obtain its address?

Tags: c++

This question is similar to others that have been asked here, but with a small twist.  I have a regular function something like this:

```
void Bar(std::initializer_list<Base*> objects);
```

Now I want to create a function template that wraps each parameter in a type that derives from `Base` and passes them to the function above.  Something like:

```
template <class... Params> void Foo(Params... parameters)
{
    Bar({&Wrapper<Params>(parameters)...});
}
```

(The class `Wrapper` is specialized for various types.)  This code actually compiles in MSVC but the compiler issues a warning because I'm taking the address of an rvalue (which is disallowed by the standard).  Is there an easy, standards conformant way to achieve the same thing?  (I think I can do this with tuples, integer_sequences, and a helper function, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.)

Comment: Make a `tuple<Wrapper<Params>...>` and then take the addresses of the tuple elements?

Comment: A tuple certainly gets me part of the way there, but is there a way to get the address of each tuple element without going through integer_sequence pain?

Comment: Instead of an initializer list of pointers, can you use an initializer list of rvalue references?

Comment: I don't believe so.  Arrays of references are illegal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the `Wrapper<T>` instances *must* exist at some address. The easy way to do this is to construct a `std::tuple<Wrapper<Params>...>` instance. The annoying part is that you have to extract the contents back out using `std::get<N>`. In C++14, [`std::index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) exists to help you with this matter.

```
template <class... Params, std::size_t... Idx>
void FooImpl(std::tuple<Wrapper<Params>...>& tup, std::index_sequence<Idx...>)
{
    Bar({ (&std::get<Idx>(tup))... });
}

template <class... Params>
void Foo(Params... parameters)
{
    std::tuple<Wrapper<Params>...> tup(Wrapper<Params>(parameters)...);
    FooImpl(tup, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Params)>());
}
```

---

If your `Bar` takes `const Wrapper<T>*`s, another option is to use C++'s constant ref rules to your advantage.

```
template <class... Params>
void FooImpl(const Wrapper<Params>&... parameters)
{
    Bar({ (&parameters)... });
}

template <class... Params>
void Foo(Params... parameters)
{
    FooImpl(Wrapper<Params>(parameters)...);
}
```

Comment: As it happens, Bar can take a const Wrapper.  That works quite nicely.  Although, truth by told, the integer_sequence solution isn't that bad now that I see it.  Thanks for your help.